# Invisible Strobe LED - Slow Mo Optical illusion

Tags: strobelight

Me and a friend got really inspired by a technical solution that we saw on kickstarter. Its a lamp that makes a optical illusion from a feather. The feather is on some way in motion by a conductor or vibrator. But, the the light above the feather are blinking (strobe,) in a frequenzy that makes the illusion of the feather moving in slow motion. In the link below you´ll see what i mean.

http://www.thisiscolossal.com/2016/08/slow-dance-picture-frame-illusion/

They mention on the link that the lamp is blinking 80 times per second. I dont know how specific that is. But maybe you guys can help me with that.

We want to make an installation in a room where there are feathers are hanging from the cealing the motion is created by a small fan and the whole lighting in the space is by a similar light as they are using in the lamp.

So, the questions is. How do we achive this?

- Is there a easy a way out just ordering a lamp that makes the same frequenzy?
- If not (propably), how can we build such a lamp?

-It seems like the lamp on the link is using some kind of micro comptuer (arduino). Is it to controll the frequenzy of the light?

- Is there any good marketplace on the web to order all the stuff from?

We have a friend who can help us out with all the electrical issues when we have a plan. Would really appricieate all tips. :D

Thanks

Comment: You appear to have understood all of the basic ideas. Yes you would need to control the blink speed of the lamp. I don't think a fan is likely to vibrate the feather fast enough to create an illusion of slow motion. Your question mentions 80Hz, so the feather would need to vibrate at 80Hz, and a fan won't likely do that. Do you realise that flashing lights can cause epileptic seizures? The insurance or liability for such a thing would put me off trying unless I really knew what I was doing, and it seems you do not.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I guess i´ll scale it down to just replicate the lamp and take it from there for some exploration. Any suggestions of how the lamp could be built? The part with the seizure is highly appriected that you mentioned. I had´nt thought of that. Its not gonna be an issue though. We´ll have to use warning signs outside the room so that people who enters are aware of the potentail hazards.

Answer (score 2):

Won't work.
The kickstarter thing depends on the object (the feather) vibrating at almost the same speed as the strobe is flashing.

If the object vibrates at the same speed as the strobe blinks, then the obect will seem to be motionless.

If the vibration rate is just a little bit faster or slower than the strobe, then you will get a slow motion effect whose speed is proportional to the difference between the vibration rate and the strobe blink rate.

If the vibration rate is really far off from the strobe blink rate, you will get seemingly random jumping of the vibrating object.

Your proposed "feathers in a fan" scheme won't have any relation between the feather motion and the strobe blink rate.

So, no slow motion.

All you will get will be random stop-motion images of the feathers, and you can get that from any commercially available strobe light.

Comment: Good point. It is the beat frequency.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a really helpfull answer. I guess i´ll skip the fan part of the idea and the part with high volume of feathers. I still want to try out the specific technique though. Lets scale it down to one feather for start. What kind of LED-light would you recommend? Do you have a favorite web shop where this potential lamp could be ordered from? Thanks again. Feeling hyped just to replicate the lamp now and take it from there :D

Comment: I'd probably use RGB LEDs rather than white LEDs.  White LEDs use a phosphor layer to get white frow what in reality is a blue LED.  I would expect them to take a little time to turn on and off.  Not enough to notice when you are just using them for light, maybe enough to be a problem when cycling them on and off 80 times a second.

Comment: You can adjust an RGB LED to give (almost) white light.  Colored might be cool, too.

Answer (score 0):

JRE's answer is the one you want - you can't do it with a fan. You need to read the link more closely. You see that coil at the bottom of the frame? It's pushing and pulling on a small magnet at the base of the feather, and the feather is vibrating at quite a high frequency. But it's not just any high frequency - it's very close to the flash rate of the light.

Now, if you use a fan, you'll have 2 problems. The first is that the vibration rate won't be fast enough. The second is that it won't be close enough to the flash rate.

So, no, your idea just won't work.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I guess i´ll scale it down to just replicate the lamp and take it from there for some exploration. Any suggestions of how the lamp could be built? :D

Comment: High power LEDs will do just fine.